# mongod instance exits on new database partition with errno :13 Permission denied

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

mongod instance on /data/db partition works fine. But when I created a new directory /data/rs1 for database and initialized mongod on it using

```
      mongod --logpath "1.log" --dbpath /data/rs1 --port 27017
```

It gives me the following error:

```
      STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/rs1/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
```

However if i try to initiate the same instance using 'sudo' , it works fine. Also, I have tried changing the permissions for /data/rs1 to the current user using chown, it doesn't work either. These are the current permissions of /data/rs1 folder

```
      drwxr-xr-x   9 user123  wheel   306 Apr 27 14:32 rs1
```

Are there any other permissions that I am missing for /data/rs1?

Note: There is no instance of mongod running when I run the above command

Comment: Off-topic here. Should be asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hint: have a look at the old directories permissions.

Comment: old dir has all the permissions on "drwxrwxrwx  30 root    wheel  1020 Apr 21 08:33 db"

Comment: Changed the permissions to drwxrwxrwx it still dint work.

Comment: Did you try chown with the -R flag?